# `TypeError: $.Tween is undefined` in FireFox

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I get this error on [this page](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/aviff/strnad_mapa2.php) in Firefox, but only sometimes:

```
TypeError: $.Tween is undefined
```

The page worked well for more than 6 month, I haven't changed the code - but strangely, the bug has appeared in the meantime. I have not upgraded any libraries. How can this happen? Can it be problem of the browser, or newer version of google maps api? Note that I still use google maps api v2 here, so the google wrapper script takes place here.

Comment: In chromium I get
```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propHooks' of undefined jquery.animate-colors_ts_1383255502.js:40
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog' ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you have jQuery included twice,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min_ts_1382746426.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min_ts_1235084541.js"></script>
```

and the second, older version, overwrites the first, newer one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use one jQuery.
2. Load the jQuery before all jQueryplugins. keep it on top of every other script tag
3. use jQuery document ready to run your code.

   ```
   $(function( ){  
       console.log( "ready!" );
   });
   ```

instead of

```
(function($) {...})(jQuery);
```

You have to clean up your code. [[Drop unnecessary parts like if(0){ ...}, move the JSON at top of the file, use the logic in bottom.]] Cleaner code will help you to find and solve issues easily.

Comment: you are totally mistaken in the point 3. This is the correct way to call jQuery. You cannot rely on `$` as it might be (and is) used by other libraries too.