# Button Color issue in Safari / Chrome - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.Tween.propHooks')

Tags: javascript, typeerror

[image]I have a Bootstrap button with a custom background color that shows correctly in Firefox but the color disappears in Safari / Chrome. When I check the debugger in those browsers I get the following initial error (screenshot also attached).

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.Tween.propHooks')
```

Does anyone know how to correct this to get the button color to show consistently across all browsers? See the link below (Our Services / Contact Us buttons under "Let's Get Started" - they should be green)

https://bankroll.marketing/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a plugin order issue. Try to move $.Tween stuff to the end of the list of included plugins.

Comment: Thanks @dhilt! I'm not sure how to implement that exactly since I'm pulling the Bootstrap files externally via CDN. I see the $.Tween line in jquery.scrollTo.js but it appears to be towards the bottom of that file.

Also, I uploaded the attachment i meant to from the browser inspector in my original post, if that helps.

Comment: I've made a little research, hope this would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228788/typeerror-tween-is-undefined-in-firefox), it's about jQuery doubling. I investigated your page source and found the following two declarations:

```
<script src="https://bankroll.marketing/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Even if this does not cause the `$.Tween` issue, you certainly should use only one jQuery on your page.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately removing that second bit of JS (part of Boostrap CDN) did not help with the button color inconsistency. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Also, not sure if this help, but this site was created by me as a sister site from "bankroll.ventures", which was developed by someone else. In an effort to create some consistency between the two, the only thing I copied over from the original site was the general CSS and customized from there. My point is, I've never had this button color inconsistency issue before using Bootstrap before so I'm not sure if it may deal with the old site CSS or using Bootstrap 4 (which I'm new too). Thanks!